# jQuery not able to acces data in .each() function

Tags: jquery, html, each

I am trying to get the element data value to match a data set but I am stuck at the .each() function.  I can't get the data value of each element. what am I doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/xyc40myc/

```
$('div').each(
function (index, el) {
    var d = el.data('value');
});
```

Comment: `$(el)` or `$(this)`. `el` is a DOM object not a jQuery object...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`el` is not the jQuery-wrapped HTML object -- it's the native HTML object. You can add the jQuery functionality to it by calling `$(el)`

```
$('div').each(function (index, el) {
    var $el = $(el),
        d = $el.data('value');

    /* ... */
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xyc40myc/2/